# Scratchy AVAudioengine on Apple Watch

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos, avaudioengine

I'm running basic oscillator and synthesizer with a sine wave (created with AVAudioEngine) using this repo https://github.com/GrantJEmerson/SwiftSynth, but sound is scratchy on Apple Watch Series 2 running OS (6.2.6), however, it sounds clear on watch simulator. What could be the reason? What is the range of frequencies Apple Watch can produce?
I'm running oscillator within the range of 100-900 Hz frequency and 0-1 amplitude. I recorded video to show it. Upper slider is frequency (100-900hz, 1 step is 100), lower is amplitude https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_q7UsXLPzV0. I tried on Series 4 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably unrelated, but I have seen a lot more noise when the watch was sitting on its charger, than when its not.

Comment: I tried with/without charger but no difference. I guess my watch Series 2 has a problem or Series 2 speakers not able to produce this sound range. I tried on Series 4 and it worked fine.